# Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've installed ruby on rails using "gem install rails" and got the message that rails has been successfully installed.
When I try to check that it has been installed successfully using "rails -v" I'm getting this error:

Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

Any ideas...?

Comment: Do you need to run 'bundle install'?

Comment: I tried running 'bundle install' but looks like either the proxy on this machine is not configured or internet access is blocked as i'm getting: Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not reach rubygems repository http://rubygems.org/. Can I not simply download this gem and install it locally?

Comment: Type ´SET HTTP_PROXY=yourproxy:port´ if you are in the windows command line and run bundle install after that

Comment: I'm on unix, I've added the proxy and made sure it is the correct one but the resource still can't be accessed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this same error because I had installed ruby and rails via rvm, but without the libssl-dev package on ubunut 11.10. To remedy, I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
rvm remove 1.9.3 #or whatever your version of ruby is
rvm cleanup all
rvm install 1.9.3
```

cd to project directory
bundle install

Now I don't seem to be getting the error anymore